# Titanium - new versions

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I created an app with Titanium, 2 years ago. I want to develop a new one, but from the beginning, it doesn't work.
I just updated the SDK to 7.4.0GA, and, when I run the command "ti create" in my console, there is an error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to load command "create"
[ERROR] SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...

at Object.<anonymous> (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\node-appc\lib\exception.js:33:27)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.defineProperty.get (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\node-appc\lib\appc.js:63:11)
```

```
at ...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\node-appc\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:2111:9
at apply (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\node-appc\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:21:25)
at ...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\node-appc\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:56:12
at _insert (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\node-appc\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:2220:9)
at Object.q.push (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\node-appc\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:2267:13)
at Object.findExecutable (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\node-appc\lib\subprocess.js:113:8)
at resolveNode (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\lib\titanium.js:97:34)
at ...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\lib\titanium.js:74:5
at Object.<anonymous> (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\lib\titanium.js:80:2)
```

I also tried with SDK 7.3.1.GA

What can I do ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Update your CLI tools. Run `npm install -g titanum appcelerator alloy` and `appc setup` to check the environment.

After that `ti create` or `appc ti create` should work

Comment: It was beacuse of my old node version ... thank you for your rapid answer :)